# Guide lines for developing Android Web application

Tags: android, css, mobile-website

Are there any guide lines for developing an Android web application? I am developing a web application and hosting it on the web, and I want to use WebView to incorporate that link in my Android application.

If we want to develop a mobile website do we need to follow any set of standards? If yes, are there any tutorials or examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3C has a list of mobile web app best practices. http://www.w3.org/TR/mwabp/

**Update:**

The Android Developer official site also has a good reference;
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html